# Attribute in SOAP PHP

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to **reproduce a XML** in **PHP SOAP**,
and I'm stuck when I try to **set an attribute**.

Example :

- [what I want to reproduce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewJZE.jpg)
- How my code looks like:

  $headerToken = new \SoapHeader($asxm,'fueloauth',$auth['accessToken']);

  $headerContentType = new \SoapHeader($asxm,'Content-Type','text/xml');

  $headerSAOPAction = new \SoapHeader($asxm,'SOAPAction','Retrieve');

  ```
  $soapClient = new \SoapClient(
      $wsdl,
      array(
          'trace'      => true,
          'location'   => $asxm,
          'soapaction' => 'retrieve',
          'exceptions ' => true,
      )
  );

  $soapClient->__setSoapHeaders(array($headerToken,$headerContentType,$headerSAOPAction));

  $RetrieveRequest = new \stdClass();

  $properties = array();
  $properties[] =  new SoapVar('email', XSD_STRING);
  $properties[] =  new SoapVar('lastclick', XSD_STRING);


  $filterClass = new \stdClass();
  $filterClass->Property = 'created_at';
  $filterClass->SimpleOperator = 'greaterThanOrEqual';
  $filterClass->Value = '08/28/2018 00:00:00 AM ';

  $params = array();
  $params['ObjectType'] = new SoapVar('DataExtensionObject[foo]', XSD_STRING, null, null, 'ObjectType' );
  $params['Properties'] = $properties;
  $params['Filter'] = new SoapVar($filterClass, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);


  $RetrieveRequest->RetrieveRequest = $params;
  ```
- [What I get with that code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4zep.jpg)

As you can see, it misses the attribute on filter :

```
    <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
```

Does someone know how I can do that in PHP SOAP ?

I've already try something like that but it doesn't works..

```
array("foo" => array("_" => "cheese", "bar"=>"moo"));
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to construct the request without wondering how to construct, then you should use a WSDL to PHP generator such as the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project. Using it will generate for you the associated classes for every parameter you need to send including the header. Handling the response will then be easier too.

Comment: I'm working with Symfony. It's my only time where I use SOAP. Extern library it's to much, for only one parameter to set.
No one else know how to set an attribute in SOAP php?

Comment: Sorry but even this little thing can be tricky, especially without having the WSDL.

Comment: If you want to have a clue, you can also use the online platform https://providr.io to generate the PHP SDK in order to identify the way the parameter is declared, it's up to you.

Comment: I can give you the WSDL link if you want.

Comment: Did you give it a try? It'll take only minutes and it would be better if you'd do it yourself ;)

Comment: I've spent more than 1 day on it .. and I'm sick of SOAP now.. Is it that easy ? Can you show me your code ?

Comment: This is exactly why I created this project and this platform ;). Adding one dependency is not an issue and having the PHP SDK will be your life saver, really! Feel free to contact me at contact@wsdsltophp.com.